# How to solve this problem of double integration?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ a function defined on the rectangle $Q=[0 \times 1] \times [0 \times 1]$,as follows:
>   $$f(x,y)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
> x+y & \text{if}\ x^2\leq y \leq2x^2  \\ 
>  0& \text{in the other points of $Q$}
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>   Represent the set of ordered of $f$ on $Q$ and calculate the volumen using double integration (Suppose that integral exist)

How?

Comment: Have you drawn the region of integration? You will need to do that before deciding between $dA=dx\,dy$ or $dA=dy\,dx$.

Comment: You ask "How?" You must sketch the graphs of $y=x^2$ and $y=2x^2$, or at least the portions which lie within the square and shade the region between them, which is the region of integration. Then you must evaluate the double integral over that region taking care to choose the order of integration carefully as suggested in my first comment.